# Simple java.net.ServerSocket based HTML5 WebSockets server for Android

Tags: java, android, html, websocket

I'm trying to setup a very simple ServerSocket in an Android app that responds to 1 browser's WebSockets request. The socket connection seems to fail on the client end (inside Google Chrome), I believe because of issues handling the WebSockets handshaking. What is the simplest approach to getting the connection setup? I'm not interested in this being production-ready since I'll only ever establish one connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebSocket is not raw TCP .. for 2 reasons: initial HTTP-based handshake + message framing after that.

So if you want to accept WS connections in a *server* running on Android, you need a WS server framework.

I'd suggest you have a look at Jetty:

http://code.google.com/p/i-jetty/

http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/

Jetty is pretty mature, solid and compliant.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I may have found a better approach using a Chrome extension which can open a regular socket connection.